# Windows 10 can't connect to this network

Tags: windows-10

For a while before this issue, my desktop has had frequent connectivity issues (slow connection, dropping offline and the like) that led me to constantly having to restart our router. According to my roommate, the wi-fi still works perfectly fine for him during these instances, so he's confused as to why I had that issue.

Then suddenly, out of nowhere, my desktop flat-out refuses to connect to the network. I've tried just about everything Google and computer forums gave me and nothing seems to work.

I've restarted the router and my computer multiple times each, I've uninstalled my drivers, updated my drivers, forgot every network on the list, used command prompt, changed the properties of my network adapter, etc.

And absolutely none of it so far has helped in any way. I'm honestly at my wit's end. Without internet connection, I can't do my job. So any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

#### My desktop flat-out refuses to connect to the network

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: That didn't seem to work.... It didn't do anything. Are there any other alternatives? I'm really sorry if I seem pushy, I'm just not sure what else to do.

Comment: @W.Devaux I don't have any more ideas :/

Comment: `netsh winsock reset` did the trick for me.

Comment: it seemed to work,  but the problem persisted for me after restart and 5-10 min of activity. I ran all the commands listed but it disconnected again, saying 'cant connect to this network', then reconnected by itself after a minute or so. It keeps happening and I am still searching for a better resolution. The issue started almost 2 days ago

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel You should ask your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue. The root cause for me was that my computer had two WiFi managers: a native Windows manager and an OEM (Dell) WiFi manager. Clearing out all saved networks from the Windows manager did nothing to fix the issue until I also removed all saved networks from the OEM manager.

Try searching for a program with "WiFi", "wireless", "network", or your computer OEM in the name to see if you might have a second network manager, too.

If this turns out to be your issue, you can disable this secondary network manager so that your computer stops saving (potentially conflicting) network information in two places.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have discovered a cause and a fix.

I'm on mobile wireless, and the router offers two networks for devices to connect to; the 2.4GHz standard wireless data and 5G on 5Ghz.

It seems that if any other device within range of the modem is connected to the 5G network the network card on the PC, which is only able to connect to the 2.4Ghz, isn't able to connect at all.

It looks like the router can only host one kind of connection at any one time.

Make sure all devices within range are connected to the same network type, if more than one is available.

Answer (score 0):

This may be random but I was having the same "Can't connect to this network" issue which happened only very occasionally in the US, Ireland and UK but sometimes multiple times per day in Belgium (Brussels). I run Windows 10 on a Lenovo 15" Flex.

I tried the various "fixes" but to no avail and resigned myself to simply rebooting. However, by pure chance I discovered that simply by closing the lid on the Laptop - which probably induces hibernation - an reopening after a couple of minutes I was able to reconnect without the reboot.
Go figure!

Answer (score -1):

thank you for the help! I tried to get into router settings but my roommate changed the password, so I ended up jumping the gun and factory resetting. Not only did it let me access the settings, it fixed my connection problem.

Now I'm not sure what exactly was the problem, but I get the suspicion that my roommate might have blacklisted me. It doesn't help his case that we're pissed at each other.

Answer (score -1):

In the adapter properties click CONFIGURE, in the ADVANCED tap click the WIRELESS PROPERTIES and change the value to 11 b/g  .